# Show Map in the Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, openstreetmap, flutter-web

I try to load map in flutter web, but no map lib is available for web except google map (I have to pay budget for this(billing)).

is there any free solutions?

Answer (score 2):

there is multiply solutions:

1.1: add `flutter_map` in pubspec.ymal

1.2: add `FlutterMap(TileLayerWidget(TileLayerOptions(urlTemplate:'')))` widget to any page you wish

1.3: in the `urltemplate` add map address provider you are interested. for example OSM map tile address provider is

```
"https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

or bing Address map provider is "https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile/png?api-version=1&layer=basic&style=main&tileSize=256&view=Auto&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}&subscription-key={subscriptionKey}","

1.4:enjoy your map

2.1: use mapbox lib
https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl